# Unable to add ImageIcon to JLabel

Tags: jlabel, imageicon

I am trying to add an image to a jLabel by using the following code:

```
ImageIcon logo = new ImageIcon("E://Logo.png");
JLabel imagelabel = new JLabel(logo);
```

When tried to execute, I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot cast javax.swing.JLabel to javax.swing.Icon
```

Can someone please let me know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is best not to have direct filepaths and instead put the images in your package folder. You must first create a JFrame and JPanel and add the JPanel to the JFrame, then create and add a label and then add the ImageIcon to the JLabel
with the .setIcon method

```
JFrame myWindow = new JFrame("Company logo");
myWindow.setVisible(true);
myWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
myWindow.setSize(500, 500);
myWindow.setResizable(true);

JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();

//add panel to JFrame
myWindow.add(myPanel);

//create image icon constructor
ImageIcon logo = new ImageIcon("logo.png");
//create label constructor
JLabel logoLabel = new JLabel("logo");
//add label to panel
myPanel.add(imageLabel)
//add icon to label 
logoLabel.setIcon(logo);
```